# How to get subbits from byte as separate integer value?

Tags: c#, c++, c, byte, bit

For example, I have byte = 245. I want to get any amount of subbits from it and convert it to integer. How I can do this?
For example, I need values from 2 to 5 bits or from 0 to 2, 5 to 7.

Any solution on C based language is fine.

Currently I use this function to get single bits:

```
public bool GetBitFromByte(byte b, byte bit_index_0_7)
{
    var bit = (b & (1 << bit_index_0_7)) != 0;

    return bit;
}
```

With this function I gather bools array and pass it into this junk function:

```
public static byte[] GetBytesFromBits(bool[] bits)
{
    int bits_amount = bits.Length;

    while (bits_amount % 8 > 0)
        bits_amount++;

    byte[] vals = new byte[bits_amount / 8];

    for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i += 8)
    {
        byte val = 0;

        for (int j = i; j < i + 8 && j < bits.Length; j++)
        {
            val <<= 1;
            if (bits[j]) val |= 1;
        }

        vals[i / 8] = val;
    }

    return vals;
}
```

Thins function logic is very weird and I looking for more clear and native way.

Comment: What have you tried, and why doesn't it work? Please give examples of input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I posted what I currently have. I looking for a more simple way without trash code.

Comment: sorry, this is not a C question. I am suprised that a member with your rep asks such a feeble question and spams tags.

Comment: What works in C will work in C# too. I need any solution. I can even make DLL on C and load it under C#.

Comment: It does not work in C. It is not C code.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I added C tag because I need C solution too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called masking. You specify the bits as powers of two (e.g. in C++, `1<<i` for bit `i`), sum these to form the mask, then use `&` on the original value and the mask.

Comment: Thank you. Will try to do it.

Comment: Ex.: `int result = input & ((1<<5) + (1<<4) + (1<<3) + (1<<2))`